# Grid layout does not display items

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

#### **XML LAYOUT:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".WRActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Mahinda Electricals"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="25px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Number Of Fields"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="20px" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_no_of_returns"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:ems="3"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_returns"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Add" />

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/returnshow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/add_returns"
            android:layout_marginTop="177dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

#### Java Code:

```
 public class WRActivity extends Activity {
        Button add_returns;
        GridLayout show_warennt_returns;
        EditText serial_no;
        EditText reason;
        EditText no_of_returns;
        Button next;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_wr);
            add_returns = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_returns);
            add_returns.setOnClickListener(oc);
            no_of_returns = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_no_of_returns);
            show_warennt_returns = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.returnshow);
    
        }
    
         
    
        OnClickListener oc = new OnClickListener() {
    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
    
                Add_text();
            }
        };
    
        public void Add_text() {
            for (int i = 0; i < Integer
                    .parseInt(no_of_returns.getText().toString()); i++) {
                GridLayout ll = new GridLayout(WRActivity.this);
                ll.setOrientation(GridLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                ll.setColumnCount(2);
                ll.setRowCount(2);
    
                TextView serial = new TextView(WRActivity.this);
                serial.setText("Serial No");
                serial.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                serial.setTag("weight");
    
                ll.addView(serial);
    
                serial_no = new EditText(WRActivity.this);
                serial_no = new EditText(WRActivity.this);
                serial_no.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                serial_no.setWidth(300);
                serial_no.setTag("Product_ID");
                ll.addView(serial_no);
    
                TextView serial1 = new TextView(WRActivity.this);
                serial1.setText("Reason");
                serial1.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                serial1.setTag("weight");
                ll.addView(serial1);
    
                reason = new EditText(WRActivity.this);
                reason.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                reason.setTag("Product_ID");
                reason.setWidth(300);
                ll.addView(reason);
    
                show_warennt_returns.addView(ll);
            }
    
        }
    
         
    }
```

I have tried above code to show dynamically two text fields  when the no of element is typed in a EditText.

It woks fine but if i type more than 10 it only shows only the first 10 only others are not displayed on the grid layout.

Comment: Can you post image, what type of layout you want?

Comment: The above code is working.All i need is add scroll view   something to   scroll the grid layout when the screen  is not enough to display the no of items

Comment: try ll.setOrientation(GridLayout.VERTICAL);

Comment: See my answer will help you.

Answer (score 2):

In `Grid View` You will Get as per the screen types or Grid View length and breadth..

if You want more than 10 which are dynamic..
You need to take a [List View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) which will help you to display async or Dynamic data..

If you want to display them in `Grid` then you can try with [Grid Lists](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/grid-lists.html)

This will Work fine for any number of dynamic data.

you need to keep them inside a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`.. as per your required orientation..

if they are more than 10 and not displaying you need to Keep a `Scroll View`

For example You can Modify Your Code at here By Placing a `Scroll view`,..
like...[image]

Which may contains a Lineary layout.. if this not worked for Your `Gridlayout` You can use `Listview` OR `GridList` as i mentioned earlier

If You want only Grid you can use Grid List.. It works FIne..

Answer (score 1):

Change GridLayout like:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/add_returns"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/returnshow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="177dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
```

#### Your whole XML is like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".WRActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Mahinda Electricals"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="25px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="30px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Number Of Fields"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20px" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/add_no_of_returns"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:ems="3"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_returns"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Add" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/add_returns"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" >

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/returnshow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="177dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code for your layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".WRActivity" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Mahinda Electricals"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="25px" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="30px" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Number Of Fields"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="20px" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/add_no_of_returns"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:ems="3"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_returns"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Add" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/add_returns"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/returnshow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```